# schedule a daily backup with SQL Server Express by using window schedule

Tags: sql-server-2008, scheduled-tasks, database-backups

i want to schedule a daily backup with SQL Server Express by using window schedule. I am able to  backup my database to D drive.But when i try to backup my database to c drive. The ms sql return me this error

```
    Msg 3201, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Cannot open backup device 'C:\inetpub\Project backup Live\LewreDB backup\Wednesday\20120502.bak'. Operating system error 5(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105).
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

Here is my query

```
   DECLARE @pathName NVARCHAR(512) 
SET @pathName = 'C:\inetpub\Project backup Live\LewreDB backup\' + DATENAME(DW,GETDATE())+'\'+ Convert(varchar(8), GETDATE(), 112) + '.bak' 
BACKUP DATABASE [LEWREDB] TO  DISK = @pathName WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'db_backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
```

Did any one face this problem before

Comment: Does the Wednesday folder already exist? Maybe to get things started you should try a simpler command, such as saving all backups to a folder that already exists...

Comment: Ya. folder is exist . I am able to backup on d drive only :(

Comment: Well, perhaps it is permission related. And perhaps D:\ is a better place for your backups anyway, no?

Comment: Do u has any solution?cos all my project is backup on C drice

Comment: Is this your local machine or is this on a web host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to backup a SQL Server Express database on a remote server to your local C: drive?

I got a similar error when I thought I could execute SQL on a remote database to backup to a location on my C:\ drive.

In any case I can recommend a workaround where you run the backup in a batch file fired by a windows scheduled task and include a line in the batch file to copy the backup from the D: drive location on the SQL Express Server to your C: drive location wherever that may be.

Answer (score 0):

This generally happens if you are using the Windows. Always run the application using Adminisatrator privileges and check if you can modify delete or create the folder in c: drive manually.